# ExtJS form getValues convert to int some values

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a search form (ExtJS 4.2) with a few fields:

```
xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
layout: 'hbox',

    items: [{

         xtype: 'combobox',
         itemId: 'cboEmployee',
         width: 400,
         store: cboEmployeeStore,
         cls: 'arigth',
         displayField: 'FullName',
         valueField: 'EmployeeId',
         queryMode: 'remote',
         fieldLabel: 'Employee',
         editable: true,
         hideTrigger: true,
         queryParam: 'searchStr',
         name: 'EmployeeId',
         minChars: 3,
         listConfig: {
             loadingText: 'Searching...',
             // Custom rendering template for each item
             getInnerTpl: function() {
                 return '<b>{EmployeeNumber}</b> / {FullName}';
             }
         }


     }, {
         xtype: 'datefield',
         fieldLabel: 'From',
         name: 'FromDate',
         format: 'd/m/Y',
         submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
         width: 180,
         labelWidth: 50,
         cls: 'arigth',
         value: new Date()
     }, {
         xtype: 'datefield',
         fieldLabel: 'To',
         name: 'ToDate',
         format: 'd/m/Y',
         submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
         width: 165,
         labelWidth: 25,
         cls: 'arigth',
         value: new Date()

     }, {
         xtype: 'button',
         action: 'search',
         text: 'Search',
         margin: '0 0 0 20'
     }]
```

Now in my controller when my button "search" is clicked I have the following code:

```
var values = {};
        form.items.each(function(f) {
            var field = f.getName();
            var value = f.getValue();

            if (field == "EmployeeId" && value == "") value = 0;
            values[field] = value;
        });
```

I can't do: `form.getValues()` because I will `EmployeeId = ""` and `EmployeeId` must be `integer`.

That's why I implement the `each` statement but...

> I get an error when the item is fieldset type because `f.getName()` is undefined so I don't know if this is the best way to do this in order to set `EmployeeId = 0` when `EmployeeId` field value is "" (empty string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `EmployeeId` to be 0 if it is an empty string, then just do that check after you get all the form values. Also, you can get the field values as their actual types, instead of all as strings, by using the `getFieldValues` function of the form.

```
// this assumes form is the FormPanel
var formValues = form.getForm().getFieldValues();
// check if the EmployeeId value is null/undefined/""
if(!formValues['EmployeeId']) {
    formValues['EmployeeId'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple but great...didnt know about getForm().getFieldValues()

Comment: Yeah, I only found that a few months ago, after using Ext for the past 2 years.